# Play Store Vanity URL?

Tags: android, google-play, vanity-url

Does anybody know if it's possible to get a vanity URL for your Android app like it is for iOS apps on the App Store?

I've searched on Google, but don't see anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Play does not offer any such URLs, sorry.

A list of your apps is available at `https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=<your publisher name>`, and you cannot change this URL.